# Stop Mobile Keyboard resizing layout in Meteor

Tags: css, cordova, meteor

I'm building a mobile app that uses the google maps js api but have an issue where whenever the mobile keyboard is brought into view it pushes the whole layout up and resizes the map. How do I stop this from happening?

I am using width 100% and height 100% which is the reason the map is being pushed up but I need the height to be 100% as mobiles comes in many different sizes.

```
.map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Very frustrating that there isn't a easy fix to make the android keyboard load on top of all the divs instead of pushing everything up and ruining the layout, or even something that keeps the height at 100% of the original screen.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this will work, but try setting your container's position to `fixed`, or try `height: 100vh` to keep the height unchanged. tell me what happens!

Comment: @Aziz Didn't seem to fix it :( thanks anyway!