# How to stop soft keyboard resizing Chrome browser window on Android mobiles?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, android-softkeyboard

I see this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195278/preventing-viewport-resize-of-web-page-when-android-soft-keyboard-is-active), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769939/how-to-prevent-android-firefox-browser-to-resize-window-when-soft-keyboard-is-on), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630234/stop-mobile-keyboard-resizing-layout-in-meteor), but could not find a clear and/or workable answer. I'm using Android 9 on a Samsung A7 (2018), running Chrome 75.

**What happens.**
I have a html form requiring keyboard input. When opened in Chrome and input is attempted, the keyboard forces the form to resize. The resizing reduces the form to about 50% of the screen height and also resizes the form width and the width/height of input fields. Any text typed is not visible until the keyboard is dismissed and the form returns to normal size. The resizing does not happen in Firefox Focus -  the keyboard slides up and over the bottom half of the form, leaving the form at 100% size.

**Update 2019 - Solution!**
I found **the answer to my question about Chrome in [a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769939/how-to-prevent-android-firefox-browser-to-resize-window-when-soft-keyboard-is-on)** about the very same problem, but in Firefox (which isn't a problem any more, at least not now with Firefox Focus 9).

Comment: Basically it is kind of difficult if bot impossible as the resizing is not happening on the html layer but on the app layer. This means that every browser could behave differently and even change behavior over time.

Answer (score 7):

its an andriod issue where the softkeyboard changes the viewport height...currently working on the same issue...this looks promising, about to implement...it sets the viewport content to explict px values

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var viewheight = $(window).height();
    var viewwidth = $(window).width();
    var viewport = $("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.attr("content", "height=" + viewheight + "px, width=" + 
    viewwidth + "px, initial-scale=1.0");
}, 300);
```

edit: worked like a charm

Comment: On my Galaxy A7, Firefox Focus no longer resizes the viewport, but Chrome still does. So I tried your solution but it made no difference, and javascript validators found lots of 'undefined' errors in it. So maybe I disunderstood it - where does your script go on in the html? Is '300' the fixed height in px? What about width? I usually just copy/tweak/paste javascript without knowing much about it.

Comment: @plugincontainer the 300 at the end of the snippet means to wait 3/10 of a second (300ms) before running (look up setTimeout)  the width and height are being set with the var viewheight / var viewwidth. make sure to delete your cache and have your javascript called at the bottom of your document

Comment: put javascript at the end of html, cleared cache but still no luck in Chrome, the form still re-sizes. With or without the script, no re-sizing in Firefox Focus or (Samsung) Internet browsers

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the height alone should do. The code below does not use jQuery.

```
setTimeout(()=>
   document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute("content", "height=" + screen.height*0.9 + "px, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
, 300);
```

I need to lower down the height to fit my case.