# Full screen background auto resize if keyboard show

Tags: html, css

i set html background full screen, in pc is working fine, but has problem in android when user input form and show keyboard ,background is auto resizing

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>x</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
  min-height:100%;height:100%;
}
html {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

SCREENSHOT :

https://prnt.sc/wd6mez - Normal

https://prnt.sc/wd6mnq - Problem

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard on Android is reducing the viewport height, and because of `background-size: cover;` the background image is naturally resizing to fit the reduced area.

Comment: So, how to fix my problem

Comment: Depending what you're doing, you might be able to move the background to a separate div, giving it its own height that's not based on the viewport height, so then any viewport resize won't affect it.

Aside from that, I think it would have to be some kind of JavaScript solution, which other people have tried to tackle before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384678/how-to-stop-soft-keyboard-resizing-chrome-browser-window-on-android-mobiles
Plenty of other similar questions on this subject that might help

Comment: problem still exist, without keyboard : https://prnt.sc/wd86xc , with keyboard  : https://prnt.sc/wd8778

Comment: you'll need to post what code changes you've made